# How to change content of website loaded in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, whitelist

I need to change content of website using jQuery loaded in iframe from other domain such this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="site.com/somepage.html></iframe>
    <script>
      $('iframe').find('div#message').value('hello');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I added target link to whitelist.
Could any helps? Thanks.

Comment: First, you might be getting stopped by cross domain restrictions. If you own both sites and you've gotten around that, your javascript is probably executing before the iframe content has loaded.

Comment: Yes I stopped by restrictions and I added other domain to whitelist to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a website of different domain you have to use parser in your server side which will parse the html from the website and then echo the parsed html to your client side

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross-site attack/mocking securities, for a long time this is no more possible in the mainframe browsers (Chrome, IE, Fire) with domains diferent of your own.

You could achieve that thru **proxying**, by proxying I mean, using a server side solution where you get  the HTML generated by "site.com" and outputs it as was in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running during runtime so it will not find the DOM of the iframe and will break. What you can do is create a function on your parent page like:

```
//On Your Parent page
function modifyIframeContent() {
     $('iframe').find('div#message').value('hello');
}
```

Then call this function from the iframe after it loads.

```
// On Your Iframe page
window.onload = function() {
    parent.modifyIframeContent();
}
```

**Of course:** Your iframe must be of same domain for this work.

Comment: Sorry, I need to make changes on other domain