# Delete some texts in an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have for example 2 websites first is : X and seconde is : Z
inside X i have an iframe that call the content of Z
so what is in Z show up in X there is a DIV in Z i dont want to show in X it has the id #footer so i want to show the content of Z in X without the footer. i tried with php file get contents but it didnt work

this is my code

```
<iframe src="Z" id="theiframe" width="100%" height="999" name="jbj" border="0" frameborder="0" marginwidth="17" marginheight="18" align="absbottom"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is the iframe being requested on the same domain as the requester?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change content of website loaded in iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516855/how-to-change-content-of-website-loaded-in-iframe)

Comment: i have the same probleme but the answers didn't work

Answer (score 2):

**You own the 2 website:**

- Just add a parameter to the URL like http://z.com/?noFooter and handle that in your Z code (Server or client side).

---

**You don't own Z :**

- You need to retrieve Z page on a server and remove the footer part from Z. Your server will act like a proxy, which mean you'll need to forward cookies and parameters if needed.
  And as stated by @blex you'll need to rewrite URLs to go through your proxy (Easier said than done).

Finally let's say : "Not your website? Don't touch it". Note that you also can go through legal problems depending on the Z owner mood.

Comment: okey , but if Z was an other website ? that mean Z isn't my website ? what i have to do ?

Comment: Thats the "you don't own Z" part.

Comment: The proxy would also need to replace any link on the page. Otherwise, clicking on an untouched Z link will result in the footer being shown again (no more proxy). That's a really tricky thing. It'll also mess up any relative link, relative image src, etc (i.e. not including the original domain in the url).

Comment: i did all those steps but there is a code in Z page ajax code it send a post to an other page

Comment: i get this error thats mean im not allowed to send a post to the server

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://salah.com/times/get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.