# Import css from iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

** This is just a theoretical question **

If I have a website containing, for example:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head
<body>
<p>blah</p>
</body>
```

And embed it in another website, that has a white background, using an iframe, could I use the css in the iframe to format the current website to give it a red background. Thanks in advance

Comment: An fortunately this is not possible since the browser strictly restrict you to access the content of an iframe unless it is from the same domain. Do you have control over content of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I think it is not possible directly. Because the DOM-Elements are different. Your own website has some DOM-tree you have formated it with your own CSS.

The included iframe website has an own different DOM-tree.

I think the iframe is not the right way for that. If it's possible, you can read and parse the output source code of your iframe website and modify it via php.

Or with Javascript Inspired from here:

[How to change content of website loaded in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516855/how-to-change-content-of-website-loaded-in-iframe)

For php you can use that snippet:

```
$iframe_source = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

Look here at the php documentation for more information:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php

Now you can echo and modify also the DOM-tree of the iframe-page. You've got the content and output from the page. You only need to echo $iframe_source.
Than you can use your CSS file and take the .class or id of the element which you want to format.

It has some advantages but also some disadvantages:

advantages

- content of iframe is also indexable
- better than iframe
- you can modify it
- its JavaScript free

disadvantes

- you need php and an server which allows file get contents
- maybe some dynamic elements in the iframe wont work

Update because it's some special case:

itty.bitty.site is very different idea from normal webpages, you can finde something about the technique behind here:

https://itty.bitty.site/#How_it_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 there is some base64encoding ans some differnt algorithm. Maybe you can ask the dev directly on

Maybe you can use some javascript to decrypt the base64 encoded strings:
But if you read the code with file_get_contents, you only get advice that you should activate javascript. That won't work ;(

The source of this itty-bitty you can find here: https://github.com/alcor/itty-bitty

Comment: Thx. What if it was using an itty.bitty site??

Comment: I updated my answer but actualy I have no good idea to handle this technique. Maybe you find some solution ;)

Comment: Maybe you can use some node.js server to encyrpt it Buffer.from(lzma.compress("Hello World", 9)).toString('base64') functions